# Best way to calculate the number of element that NOT appear in another table

Tags: c#, mysql, query-performance

Consider the following situation

```
TableA                                                 TableB
+------------+----------+----------+----------+        +---------+  
|Column1     | Column2  | Column3  | Column4  |        | entB    |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+        +---------+
| zzzxxxx    | NULL     | NULL     | zzzyyyy  |        | zzzxxxx | 
+------------+----------+----------+----------+        +---------+
| zzzqqqq    | NULL     | SomeText | NULL     |        | zzzyyyy |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+        +---------+
| NULL       | zzzxxxx  | zzzxxx   | NULL     |        | zzzwwww |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+        +---------+
| zzzyyyy    | zzzyyyy  | zzzwwww  | SomeText |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

where z,y,x = 1-9 and some text can contain any number or letter- Table B can't have null values in ent B column.

i need to find the total of the values that are in Table A that are not in Table B. The column in table A does not contain unique(distinct) value and may be null.

My first attempt was the following and query

```
$"select count(1) from " +
$"(" +
$"  select distinct Column1 from {TableA} where Column1 not in (select entB from {TableB})" +
$" union" +
$"  select distinct Column2 from {TableA} where Column2 not in (select entB from {TableB})" +
$" union" +
$"  select distinct Column3 from {TableA} where Column3 not in (select entB from {TableB})" +
$" union" +
$"  select distinct Column4 from {TableA} where Column4 not in (select entB from {TableB})" +
$") as t"
```

This was fine until i had to test this on a TableA with ~70000000 rows and ~100000 rows for TableB where this query took way too long to be executed. I am looking for a way to decrease the time.

I read that using `Distinct` and `Union` is an easy way to kill the performance, so i was thinking to try something like this

```
SELECT Column1
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.Column1 = b.entB and a.Column1 is not null ) 
and Column1 is not null)
```

get the result, save it in a DataTable, then repeat the same query for the other 3 column and merge the result checking the duplicates in memory.

Do you know if there are better solution?

EDIT: i have edited the table to show better how my data looks like. In the example, i expect as result the value "2" since there are 2 values (SomeText and zzzqqqq) that are not present in TableB

Comment: You seem to have several column2's. As such, this question is unintelligible. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry it was a clear typo while trying to format the question... it is fixed now

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design. Consider whether there's scope to revise that.

Comment: Use Left Outer Join.   the number of items are the DefaultEmpty.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @jdweng DefaultEmpty should be used in my code after i have executed the 4 queries?

Comment: You originally didn't include that it worked until you tested with huge number or rows.  You have to check task manager and see how much memory is being used when you have a lot of rows.  where you have this amount of data it is much better to run as a stored procedure in the database.

Comment: There are some ambiguities in your specification.  Please provide several lines from each table and say what the results should be.  Be sure to include any edge cases.

Comment: @RickJames i have updated the table trying to show better how my data looks like. I can't show the exact data unfortunatly. Table A has 20+ columns but i have shown the relevant ones (which are indexed) and the index is present also in entB column of table B. My requirements, as stated before, is to give the total number of distinct values that are in the TableA that are not present in the TableB

Comment: Thanks.  However,...  "total of the values" -- I don't see any numbers to add up.  Do you mean "count of matching values"?  Please provide the expected _output_ for that sample dataset.

Comment: @RickJames it is in the question. In the example provided i expect "2", since there are 2 values in table A that are not present in the table B

Answer (score 2):

Once we get past all the grumbling about how `TableA` isn't normalized, this isn't hard to do.

I guess you want a count of the values of your four columns in TableA that don't match `TableB`. If you want something more complex, with respect, take the time to figure out how to describe it very precisely.

Start with a subquery that gives you the values from `TableA` to compare.  Because we use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`, we get `SELECT DISTINCT` for free. (SQL manipulates sets.)

```
         SELECT Column1 AS ent FROM TableA
         UNION
         SELECT Column2 AS ent FROM TableA
         UNION
         SELECT Column3 AS ent FROM TableA
         UNION
         SELECT Column4 AS ent FROM TableA
```

Then, use the `LEFT JOIN .... IS NULL` pattern to get the items that don't match.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_unmatched_items
    FROM (        SELECT Column1 AS ent FROM TableA
                  UNION
                  SELECT Column2 AS ent FROM TableA
                  UNION
                  SELECT Column3 AS ent FROM TableA
                  UNION
                  SELECT Column4 AS ent FROM TableA
         ) a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ent = b.entB
   WHERE b.entB IS NULL
```

That `WHERE...IS NULL` picks up the rows from your subquery that failed the `ON` condition in the left join.

To make this decently fast, I think you will need separate indexes on each column from `TableA` that's involved in this, as well as an index on `entB` in `TableB`. But you'll need to try it out, and do `EXPLAIN` if it still doesn't meet your performance needs.

Unless the machine running MySQL is really short on RAM, MySQL should handle this stuff reasonably efficiently.

**Pro tip:** You already know this. Denormalized tables like `TableA` can really mess up query performance.

Comment: `endB` had better be the beginning of some index in `TableB`.  Still, the query may take hours since it needs to do 4 table scans of 70M rows; plus 4*70M lookups into the smaller table.

Comment: i wanted to let you know that your solution, at least in my environment is by far the slowest. The first query i proposed took ~5 min to be executed, while the version with not exist took ~2 minuts and half. Your query take 27 minutes to be completed.

Comment: Suggest changing `UNION` to `UNION DISTINCT` since the algorithm embodied in the query depends on dedupping.